can't find the correct versions of Wayland inserts for QT6
To all:
I am running the following:
Windows11 Pro
WSL2
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
from PyQt6 import QtCore 6.7.0
from PyQt5 import QtCore 5.15.8
I can make this run string work: QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xdb openmc-plotter
So I know the path statement is correct, and the openmc-plotter app works.
I would like to have this ( and other apps) work with the Wayland insert.
Since the $HOME/anaconda3/lib/qt6/plugins/platforms/ folder did not contain land-generic.so or libqwayland-egl.so,
I copied versions from other locations under a QT6 heading directory, into this folder.
When I execute this string, QT_QPA_PLATFORM=Wayland openmc-plotter
I get the following:
qt.core.plugin.loader: In $HOME/anaconda3/lib/qt6/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so:
Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (6.7.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In $HOME/anaconda3/lib/qt6/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so:
Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (6.7.0) [release]
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "$HOME/anaconda3/lib/qt6/plugins/platforms"
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, vnc, linuxfb, xcb.
How can I get versions of libqwayland-generic.so and libqwayland-egl.so that will solve this dependency?
Thanks
Ron
I copied versions from other locations under a QT6 heading directory, into the $HOME/anaconda3/lib/qt6/plugins/platforms folder.
I was expecting this to solve the issue.
When I execute this string, QT_QPA_PLATFORM=Wayland openmc-plotter
I get the following:
qt.core.plugin.loader: In $HOME/anaconda3/lib/qt6/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so:
Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (6.7.0) [release]
qt.core.plugin.loader: In $HOME/anaconda3/lib/qt6/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so:
Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (6.7.0) [release]
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "$HOME/anaconda3/lib/qt6/plugins/platforms"
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, vnc, linuxfb, xcb.
